# how to update all the entries except one in a particular column using Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table and this table contain multiple columns. I want to know how to update all the entries except one in a particular column. I don't want to use more than one update query.

If you have any idea about this please share me. Your help is definitely appreciated.

**Table Structure**

[image]

**Query** (I tried this myself but i am confused regarding this also working)

```
UPDATE `table` SET STATUS = 0;
UPDATE `table` SET STATUS = 1 WHERE id = 4;
```

**My Question is** how to combine these queries in one query

Comment: If you are confused about the `UPDATE table SET STATUS = 0;` working, there is no condition on the `UPDATE` (no `WHERE` clause), therefore all rows are updated. Compare to `SELECT * FROM table` vs. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 4`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To update all rows but one:

```
UPDATE `table` SET STATUS = 0 WHERE id <> 4;
```

If you need to explicitely set the status of the row where `id = 1`, I suggest you do it in a second separate query.

If you *really* want to do it in one query:

```
UPDATE `table` SET STATUS = IF(id = 4, 1, 0);
```

Comment: Updating a column in every row of the table is inherently a performance problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
UPDATE table SET STATUS = (id = 4);
```

Note that you can use any boolean condition:

```
UPDATE table SET STATUS = (id IN (4, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 4 AS 'id', 1 AS 'status') AS tmp USING(id)
SET table.status = COALESCE(tmp.status, 0)
```